# Unable to get promises to work, subsequent promises not being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm trying to extend some existing code with additional promises, but they are a new topic for me at the moment and i'm obviously missing something. This is running as part of a build scrip for npm.

All i am currently trying to make happen is for the final then to be called after the pack operation has happened for each architecture. I have tried wrapping it in a

```
return new Promise
```

But at the moment i am not returning anything from that function so i'm  not sure what i should include in the resolve call at the end. If i just call the resolve with a true nothing happens, and wrapping it in a promise seems to cause the function to not actually run, and no errors are caught anywhere?

I'm guessing i am going about this completely wrong, all i want to achieve is to run another function once the previous one has completed?

Here's the code as it stands with the additional .then that i can't get to be called.

```
function build(cfg) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    webpack(cfg, (err, stats) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(stats);
    });
  });
}

function startPack() {
  console.log('start pack...');
  build(electronCfg)
    .then(() => build(cfg))
    .then(() => del('release'))
    .then(paths => {
      if (shouldBuildAll) {
        // build for all platforms
        const archs = ['ia32', 'x64'];
        const platforms = ['linux', 'win32', 'darwin'];

        platforms.forEach(plat => {
          archs.forEach(arch => {
            pack(plat, arch, log(plat, arch));
          });
        });
      } else {
        // build for current platform only
        pack(os.platform(), os.arch(), log(os.platform(), os.arch()));
      }
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('then!');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}

function pack(plat, arch, cb) {
  // there is no darwin ia32 electron
  if (plat === 'darwin' && arch === 'ia32') return;

  const iconObj = {
    icon: DEFAULT_OPTS.icon + (() => {
      let extension = '.png';
      if (plat === 'darwin') {
        extension = '.icns';
      } else if (plat === 'win32') {
        extension = '.ico';
      }
      return extension;
    })()
  };

  const opts = Object.assign({}, DEFAULT_OPTS, iconObj, {
    platform: plat,
    arch,
    prune: true,
    'app-version': pkg.version || DEFAULT_OPTS.version,
    out: `release/${plat}-${arch}`,
    'osx-sign': true
  });

  packager(opts, cb);
}
```

Comment: `cfg` is undefined variable here `.then(() => build(cfg))` and should cause rejection in strict mode. It should be `then((cfg) => build(cfg))`. Which may or make not sense, it is another question if `webpack` is supposed to be called on its own result twice.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, cfg is defined further up the file, as it is right here this runs fine, what i can't get to happen is the final .then to be called?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this code. The second to last `.then` isn't even asynchronous (not returning a promise), so you don't even need another `.then` to extend this code, as written (but it should work). I suggest you reverify your assumptions.

Comment: You should see the 'then!' output almost immediately, before packing happens. I now see `pack` takes a callback `cb`, so I suspect you want it to wait for all those to finish? If so, then that won't happen unless you make `pack` also return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what `log` is, but if it's a plain logging function, then it looks like you're passing in `undefined` (the result from calling `log(...)`) as the `cb` argument to `pack`. Perhaps you meant:

```
pack(plat, arch, () => log(plat, arch));
```

In any case, this won't do anything to wait for packing to finish. I don't know why you're not seeing any console output, but if you're looking for this output to happen after all the packing has finished, then you need to wrap `packager` in a promise. Something like:

```
var pack = (plat, arch) => new Promise(resolve => {
    // ...
    packager(opts, resolve);
});
```

And then use `Promise.all` instead of `forEach` to do all the packaging (in parallel if that's OK):

```
.then(paths => {
  if (!shouldBuildAll) {
    return pack(os.platform(), os.arch());
  }
  return Promise.all(['linux', 'win32', 'darwin'].map(plat =>
      Promise.all(['ia32', 'x64'].map(arch => pack(plat, arch))));
})
.then(() => console.log('then!'))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```